# getUrl fails to generate proper key, so admin link redirects to dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, user

In my block file:

```
$link = $this->getUrl('admin/user/edit', ['user_id' => 2]);
```

It generates a link that looks right but it redirects to the dashboard and comparing the link in the admin to that same user while logged in the only difference is the key.

I tried ones without arguments too:

```
$link = $this->getUrl('admin/user/index');
$link = $this->getUrl('admin/user/index',['_use_rewrite' => true]);
```

Both fail to generate a link that doesn't redirect to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out after hours and hours... because you know Magento2's system is intuitive and easy to use and is so well documented and isn't esoteric at allllll....

```
$link = $this->getUrl('adminhtml/user/edit', ['user_id' => 2]);
```

Then it magically rewrites it to admin/user/edit and the url is correct with the correct key.  Why?  Because some developer decided why, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

**For Magento 1**

```
<?php $link = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/user/index"); ?>
```

**For Magento 2**

```
protected $urlBuider;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    ....
}

$link = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('admin/user/index', $paramsHere = array());
```

Comment: Isn't Mage:: for magento 1?

Comment: I didnt notice that you looking for magento 2

Comment: no worries :)  the method above is giving me the exact same key as my example so it still redirects to the dashboard.  The working link I click in the admin is admin/user/edit/user_id/2/key/815ef162397171cbc171c9ecd33c881f0913ff8b3718a5353f6cc1fe1d4935e8/ but the link I am getting from these methods is admin/user/edit/user_id/2/key/0e41556e1f504e973dd05148abe6a5637141238554f4b1cd7fe000e30612ab1a/

Comment: By the way in which file you are trying to add this link?

Comment: Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info.php which class Info extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\AbstractOrder

Comment: well the magento 1 example gave me an idea that worked at least.